# Microsoft Azure Public pricing

Tags: azure

Does Microsoft Azure provides an API endpoint to fetch the public pricing for all the virtual machines families just like the AWS Public Pricing Catalogue?

I've been able to find the pricing for resources in a subscription id which is not exactly what I want, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the official MS Azure calculator here:
[Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)